# python - combine 2 time formats

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def convert(time):
    pos = ["s","m","h","d"]
    time_dict = {"s": 1,"m": 60,"h": 3600,"d": 24*3600 }
    unit = time[-1]
    if unit not in pos:
        return -1
    try:
        timeVal = int(time[:-1])
    except:
        return -2

    return timeVal*time_dict[unit]
```

Currently, this is my code and I'm using it to translate Strings like `5d` or `30m` to seconds. And that's work, but if I try to combine them (like `5d 30m`, it gives me the output `-2`. I don't really see what's wrong here.

Comment: You cannot convert `5d 30` to an integer

Comment: What do you mean by __combine them__

Comment: @PCM i want to get the total number of seconds returned. Like `86400` for `1d`.

Comment: What do you get instead of `86400`

Comment: I want to use multiple formats at the same time, like I said `2d 30m` - and that doesn't work.

Comment: As side note: you should avoid using `try...except:` (so-called bare except) at least during development as it often hide useful information, for example here if not that you would became aware that `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're only checking the last character, you need to parse the string to find each individual group and then work off of that

```
import re
def convert(time):
    time_dict = {"s": 1,"m": 60,"h": 3600,"d": 24*3600 }
    regex_groups = re.findall("(\d+)([smhd])", time)
    return sum(int(x) * time_dict[y] for x,y in regex_groups)
```

Comment: How can i add month and year support for that?

Answer (score 0):

*I don't really see what's wrong here.*

Lets say you provided `5d 30m` as input, `[:-1]` does jettison last character which result in `5d 30`. You then try to convert it to `int` which fails, as `d` is not allowed in integer representation.

You need first to tokenize elements then convert every piece to value in seconds then sum them together, simplified example with `h` and `m` only:

```
def to_seconds(token):
    q = {"h":3600,"m":60}
    return int(token[:-1])*q[token[-1]]
def convert(time):
    return sum(to_seconds(i) for i in time.split())
print(convert("5h 30m"))
```

output

```
19800
```

Disclaimer: this solution assumes that elements are whitespaces sheared